# Using spark-redshift on EC2/EMR in different region than redshift cluster and S3

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

We are using the spark-redshift library to unload from our RS cluster.

The S3 bucket and cluster are both operating in the us-west-2 region. However, our EMR is running the us-east-1 region.

We keep getting the error that we must use the correct endpoint.

`Invalid operation: S3ServiceException:The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint.`

Is there a way to unload from RS from a different region, provided S3 is in the same region as the cluster? I'm not aware of any hard limitation in this scenario. Here is our unload command:

```
var df = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.redshift")
  .option("url", "jdbc:redshift://URL")
  .option("query", "(SELECT count(*) from TABLE)")
  .option("tempdir","s3a://WESTBUCKET/PATH")
  .option("region","us-west-2").load
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 4789 release of Redshift will add the REGION option to the UNLOAD statement, so you can specify the bucket region.

> Amazon Redshift: Added support for cross region UNLOAD with REGION
>   parameter.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/rs-mgmt-cluster-version-notes.html#rs-mgmt-cluster-version-notes-104515

Your cluster will most likely be upgraded to this release during one of the maintenance windows in the time period specified for this release.

Comment: I think this is exactly what we are looking for. Thank you!